# "UseInMemoryDatabase", but app still uses my main DB

Tags: c#, .net, api, testing, xunit

I am trying to set up my project to run integration tests for api.
In my test project I "rewrite" services to use InMemoryDatabase like this:

```
public class IntegrationTest
{
    protected readonly HttpClient TestClient;

    protected IntegrationTest()
    {
        var applicationFactory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>().WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.RemoveAll(typeof(DataContext));
                services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("Test Db");
                });
            });
        });

        TestClient = applicationFactory.CreateClient();
    }

    protected async Task AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        TestClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", await GetJwtAsync());
    }

    protected async Task<Category> CreateCategoryAsync(Category category)
    {
        var response = await TestClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Categories", category);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Category>();
    }
    private async Task<string> GetJwtAsync()
    {
        var response = await TestClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Categories", new CategoryDTO { CategoryName = "Test category" });
        var postResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CategoryDTO>();
        return postResponse.CategoryName;
    }
}
```

Test for example:

```
[Fact]
    public async Task Get_ReturnCategory()
    {
        //Arrange
        await AuthenticateAsync();
        var createdCategory = await CreateCategoryAsync(new Category { CategoryName = "Intest category"});

        //Act
        var response = await TestClient.GetAsync($"api/Categories/{createdCategory.Id.ToString()}");

        //Assert
        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var returnedCategory = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Category>();
        returnedCategory.Should().Be(createdCategory.Id);
        returnedCategory.CategoryName.Should().Be("Intest category");
    }
```

Why new instances are still appearing in my main mssql db? How I fix this?